# Why should I hide "consumer secret"?

Tags: javascript, oauth

I'm currently writing a twitter client using javascript, then found out many people reminded javascript developers about not revealing "consumer secret". But they never said why.

So why is it so important to hide my consumer_secret? If anyone want to show my "via My_App" on his app, making the name My_App more famous, why should I worried about anything? After all, you can't get any useful information out of my consumer_secret, the user information is protected by both https and token_secret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A malicious developer could create a spam application using your consumer secret. If enough spam accounts are using the spam app Twitter may disable the entire consumer key at which point your entire application will no longer work with Twitter.

Comment: But it is too easy to apply for an app on twitter, and why would a spam developer even bother to use my app?

Comment: Because it isn't tied to them or their Twitter accounts. Plus if they steal the secret of a popular app Twitter might have to delay in revoking the secret will the real app dev pushes an update with new tokens.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the consumer secret as a password -- it identifies your client to the server.  Anyone with your consumer secret can pretend to be your app.

So you need to keep it secure, and you don't want to "hide" it; you want to encrypt it.  This should happen on the server, *never* in the javascript app that you send to the user.

You can find a lot of helpful information at Google's [support page](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=162105).

Comment: If you have a javascript-based client-side Twitter app, how do you "hide" the secret or encrypt the secret?  It has to be available to the client-side javascript so it can be sent to the Twitter server, right?